# What is "The Best" U.S. Currency RegEx?

Tags: regex, currency

A quick search for currency regex brings up [a lot of results](https://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=currency&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20).

The problem I have in choosing one is that regex is difficult to verify without testing all the edge cases. Does anyone have a regex for U.S. currency that has been *thoroughly tested*?

My only requirement is that the matched string is U.S. currency and parses to `System.Decimal`:

```
[ws][sign][digits,]digits[.fractional-digits][ws] 

Elements in square brackets ([ and ]) are optional. 
The following table describes each element. 

ELEMENT             DESCRIPTION
ws                  Optional white space.
sign                An optional sign.
digits              A sequence of digits ranging from 0 to 9.
,                   A culture-specific thousands separator symbol.
.                   A culture-specific decimal point symbol.
fractional-digits   A sequence of digits ranging from 0 to 9.
```

Comment: I'd add one more potential issue - parentheses used instead of a sign. It's a fairly common convention in accounting.

Comment: The `MSDN` one you cited allows `00000000042`.  Bleh.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

here's some stuff from the makers of Regex Buddy.  These came from the library so i'm confident they have been thoroughly tested.

Number: Currency amount (cents mandatory)
Optional thousands separators; mandatory two-digit fraction

```
Match; JGsoft:
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}$
```

Number: Currency amount (cents optional)
Optional thousands separators; optional two-digit fraction

```
Match; JGsoft:
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

Number: Currency amount US & EU (cents optional)
Can use US-style 123,456.78 notation and European-style 123.456,78 notation.  Optional thousands separators; optional two-digit fraction

```
Match; JGsoft:
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:[0-9]*(?:[.,][0-9]{2})?|(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?|(?:\.[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9]{2})?)$
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the Regex Buddy library?  Is it posted online?

Comment: i don't have a link to it; it's part of the software.

Comment: Very old now but this regex does not handle the optional commas very well. The number `11111111,111,111111.11` is obviously malformed, but this regex will match it.

Comment: @OGHaza note comment on thousands separators.  also, note the question did not ask nor require thousands separators. the answer was for the question asked not for a different question.

Comment: @Keng, I agree it meets OPs needs, was only making note since this is the answer to a question called `What is “The Best” U.S. Currency RegEx`

Comment: @OGHaza but you down-voted it for answering the question asked, that's what confuses me.  it answers the OP's question, notes something the OP may not have foreseen, and you still down-voted it?

Comment: I think we can fix the optional comma issue by replacing `(?:,?[0-9]{3})*` with something like `(?:(,[0-9]{3})*|([0-9]{3})*)`. Commas everywhere or no commas.

Comment: On the 3rd regex, you don't need to escape the periods in Xcode, so you get a warning. Fix: `^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:[0-9]*(?:[.,][0-9]{2})?|(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:.[0-9]{2})?|(?:.[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9]{2})?)$`

Comment: @Keng No they down voted because this answer is wrong. It actually does not fulfill the requirements OP wanted because the matched string is not U.S. Currency. This answer is misleading to future visitors like myself that actually wanted a regexp that only matched U.S. Currency, unless they noticed regularmike's comment. Along with that this answer also accepts leading zeros such as: `01234`.

Comment: [0-9]{1,3} allows numbers like 0,123. I'd recommend [1-9][0-9]{0,2}

Comment: This answer would be improved with example numbers above the regex, rather than (or as well as) word descriptions.

Comment: What about this one? (?:\,|\.?\d)*

Answer (score 25):

I found this regular expression on line at www.RegExLib.com by Kirk Fuller, Gregg Durishan

I've been using it successfully for the past couple of years.

```
"^\$?\-?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\-?\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\(\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))\)$"
```

Comment: While my testing is not authoritative, this one worked for me. Accepted: 123  123.00   $123.00   1234   $1234   $1234.00  $1,234.00  Rejected: #123  1,2,34  Only problem I found is that it accepted 123.4

Comment: Works, guys at work want 123.4 as a valid dollar amount.

Comment: this is the way

Comment: How does one run this in javascript?

Comment: For my case, 123.4 is fine - if people don't know how to export from Excel properly they might export 123.4 instead of .40, and I found Tabula sometimes misses the last digit on some imports. 

This is the way.

Comment: Whoops, I found a failure. Navy Federal Credit Union uses a - at the END of the string for debits, oddly. I guess I'll need to roll up my sleeves and figure out how to add it.

Answer (score 11):

Not thoroughly tested at all (I just wrote it!), but seems to behave correctly:

```
^-?(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,?\d{3})*)(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Test set:

```
0
1
33
555
4,656
4656
99,785
125,944
7,994,169
7994169
0.00
1.0
33.78795
555.12
4,656.489
99,785.01
125,944.100
-7,994,169
-7994169.23 // Borderline...

Wrong:
000
01
3,3
5.
555,
,656
99,78,5
1,25,944
--7,994,169
0.0,0
.10
33.787,95
4.656.489
99.785,01
1-125,944.1
-7,994E169
```

Note: Your System.Decimal is locale dependent, hard to make in regex, except perhaps when building it. I assumed digits being grouped by three, even if in some cultures (locales) there are different rules.
It is trivial to add whitespace around it.

Comment: @RonRoyston The original question required digits to be present before the decimal symbol... (see the `.10` case in the wrong testset). And `0.75` does pass, when I go to https://regex101.com/, paste my expression and add your two cases.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to account for human error you could make the the regex more forgiving when matching currency.  I used Keng's 2nd nice regex and made it a bit more robust to account for typo's.

```
\$\ ?[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9])*(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?
```

This will match any of these proper or mangled currency figures but not pick up the extra junk on the end after the space:

```
$46,48382
$4,648,382
$ 4,648,382
$4,648,382.20
$4,648,382.2
$4,6483,82.20
$46,48382 70.25PD
$ 46,48382 70.25PD
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Keng is perfect, I just want add that for working with 1 or 2 decimals (for third version) :

```
"^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:[0-9]*(?:[.,][0-9]{1})?|(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?|(?:\.[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?)$
```

NET FIDDLE:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/1mUpX2

Answer (score 3):

[image: regex_expression]

`/^[-]?[$]\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*\.\d{2}$/` is what I came up with - I see similar answers, but I just used `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: Where does this screenshot come from?

Comment: It's from https://regexr.com/  under the regex you can click "Tests"

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following regular expression for currency validation:

```
^-?0*(?:\d+(?!,)(?:\.\d{1,2})?|(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?))$
```

You can also allow optional leading dollar sign:

```
^\$?-?0*(?:\d+(?!,)(?:\.\d{1,2})?|(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?))$
```

You can easily add testing for parentheses instead of sign by adding

```
\( and \)
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is a few years old, so I wanted to give an updated answer.

I have used [jQuery InputMask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) and it works very well for input/format masking (such as phone numbers, etc) but it does NOT really work well for currency from my experience.

For currency, I strongly recommend [autoNumeric](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric) jQuery plugin. It's well-maintained and they've basically "thought of everything" I could want for currency.

I actually use a combination of both of these plugins for formatting phone numbers, number formats (ISBN, etc), as well as currencies (US currency mostly).

Keep in mind that `jquery.inputmask` is mostly about controlling a value's format, whereas `autoNumeric` is about specifically controlling the format of currency.

Comment: Indeed, trying to use a regex only will only lead you to pain and despair. Take a look at the number of AutoNumeric lines of code (as of today) : `~/dev/autoNumeric »  cat src/*|wc -l ` -> **10851**. This is just the most complete library today for formatting currencies, and it's *thoroughly tested* indeed ;) *(Disclaimer; I'm one of it's maintainer)*

Comment: Can you give an example with using this library to extract a currency value from a string?

Comment: @Ari: these libraries are more about controlling the format of data when a user enters them into input fields; I don't use them for extracting currency from strings.  To extract currency from a string you could use regex to remove anything that isn't 0-9 and a decimal, and then convert that to a float, and then I recommend storing monetary values as cents in the DB.  Untested pseudocode: `"$123,456.78".gsub(/^[0-9]\./, "").to_f => 123456.78` (note this allows multiple decimal places, but proof of concent).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at this too and have come to the conclusion that it is best to build the regex based on the current culture.
We can use the

```
CurrencyPositivePattern 
CurrencyGroupSeparator
CurrencyDecimalSeparator
```

properties of `NumberFormatInfo` to get the required format.

Edit: something  like this

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
      // Assign needed property values to variables.
      string currencySymbol = nfi.CurrencySymbol;
      bool symbolPrecedesIfPositive = nfi.CurrencyPositivePattern % 2 == 0;
      string groupSeparator = nfi.CurrencyGroupSeparator;
      string decimalSeparator = nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;

      // Form regular expression pattern.
      string pattern = Regex.Escape( symbolPrecedesIfPositive ? currencySymbol : "") + 
                       @"\s*[-+]?" + "([0-9]{0,3}(" + groupSeparator + "[0-9]{3})*(" + 
                       Regex.Escape(decimalSeparator) + "[0-9]+)?)" + 
                       (! symbolPrecedesIfPositive ? currencySymbol : "");
```

refer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx

Comment: @Robert-levy: added reference msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx

Comment: This could probably be improved by saying that it is for c#

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with this (taking bits and pieces from some of the regexs above).  Only handles up to thousands, but should be not too hard to extend that

```
case class CurrencyValue(dollars:Int,cents:Int)
def cents = """[\.\,]""".r ~> """\d{0,2}""".r ^^ {
  _.toInt
}
def dollarAmount: Parser[Int] = """[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}""".r ~ opt( """[\.\,]""".r ~> """\d{3}""".r) ^^ {
  case x ~ Some(y) => x.toInt * 1000 + y.toInt
  case x ~ None => x.toInt
}
def usCurrencyParser = """(\$\s*)?""".r ~> dollarAmount ~ opt(cents) <~ opt( """(?i)dollars?""".r) ^^ {
  case d ~ Some(change) => CurrencyValue(d, change)
  case d ~ None => CurrencyValue(d, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use:

**Without leading + or -**

```
^\$\d{1,3}\.[0-9]{2}$|^\$(\d{1,3},)+\d{3}\.[0-9]{2}$
```

**With optional leading + or -**

```
^[+-]?\$\d{1,3}\.[0-9]{2}$|^[+-]?\$(\d{1,3},)+\d{3}\.[0-9]{2}$
```

net fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/compsult/9of63cwk/12/

Answer (score 1):

Using Leandro's answer I added `^(?:[$]|)` to the beginning to allow for a preceding dollar sign

```
^(?:[$]|)[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:[0-9]*(?:[.,][0-9]{1})?|(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?|(?:\.[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?)$
```

*This matched*

```
136,402.99
25.27
0.33
$584.56
1
00.2
3,254,546.00
$3,254,546.00
00.01
-0.25
+0.85
+100,052.00
```

*Did Not Match*

```
11124.52
234223425.345
234.
.5234
a
a.23
32.a
a.a
z548,452.22
u66.36
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one? Shorter and elegant

```
(?:\,|\.?\d)*
```

Answer (score 0):

posting because i didn't see an answer that disallows you from putting more than 3 digits before the a potential first comma. This worked for me:

`^\$?[0-9]{1,3}((,[0-9]{3})*|([0-9]{3})*)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

basically replaces`(?:,?\d{3})*` in other answers with `((,[0-9]{3})*|([0-9]{3})*)`. you can add back the `(?:` if you want, but I don't fully understand why that's needed in the first place.