# Reg-Exp for 0,0.0 or 100.20 or 0.99 or 9999.99

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex

I want to be able to allow 0 or 0.0 or 100.20 or 1000 or 0.99

I want to enter 4 digit+decimal point+2 digit

Where decimal & 2 digit are not mandatory & out of 4 digits I want to allow 1 digit too

I want the exact regex to match this.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354044/what-is-the-best-u-s-currency-regex/354365#354365

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/\d{1,4}(\.(\d{1,2}))?/
```

This says "one to four digits optionally followed by a `.` and one or two digits".

Surround that with `\b` if you want to match (and extract in the following) a word within a string:

```
/\b(\d{1,4}(\.(\d{1,2}))?)\b/
```

If you want the string to match strictly that pattern and nothing else (i.e. nothing before or after), you can anchor it with `^` and `$`:

```
/^\d{1,4}(\.(\d{1,2}))?$/
```

Comment: I guess OP want's to anchor it too.

Comment: @Qtax: added anchoring and word boundary variants.

Comment: last one is more beneficial.Thanks