# Currency Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I think I created a working regular expression for what I need.  Just wondering if anyone can break it or see a shorter way to write it.

The regular expression should validate the following...

- Dollar sign optional
- Negative numbers signified with parenthesis, not a minus
- If negative, dollar sign should be outside the parenthesis
- Commas are optional
- Max number is 999999.99
- Min number is (999999.99)
- Decimals do not have to be supplied, but if so, no more than two
  digits

So here are some examples of valid ones...

```
9
$9
$0.99
($999,999.99)
(999999)
($999999)
(999,999)
99,999.9
```

This is what I have come up with:

```
^\$?(((\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,2})?)|(\d{1,3},\d{3}(\.\d{1,2})?)|\(((\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,2})?)|(\d{1,3},\d{3}(\.\d{1,2})?))\)))$
```

CORRECTION, my spec was wrong, if the dollar sign is used it must be INSIDE the parenthesis.

Comment: 1: this might belong on [codereview.se]. 2: What language is the regex in? 3: what i18n considerations have you taken? 4: `1.000,00`, `3.000`

Comment: You seem to have unnecessary many parenthesis. Do you need all of them for matching groups?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is "The Best" U.S. Currency RegEx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354044/what-is-the-best-u-s-currency-regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express "between one and six digits; comma before the last three digits is optional" a bit more tersely as `\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})?`. This also allows you to include only two copies of `(\.\d{1,2})?`: one for positive and one for negative, instead of one for positive-without-comma, one for positive-with-comma, etc.

Also, `\d{1,2}` can be shortened slightly to `\d\d?`, though I'm not sure if that's an improvement.

So, barring some notation like `(?(1))` to test if a backreference is set, here's the shortest version I see:

```
^(\$?\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})?(\.\d\d?)?|\(\$?\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})?(\.\d\d?)?\))$
```

One perhaps-undesirable aspect of your regex, and of this one, is that they will allow something like `$00,012.7`, even though no one uses leading zeroes that way. You can address that by requiring the first digit to be nonzero, and then adding a special case to handle `$0` and `(0.12)` and so on:

```
^(\$?(0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(,?\d{3})?)(\.\d\d?)?|\(\$?(0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(,?\d{3})?)(\.\d\d?)?\))$
```

**Edited to add:** using a lookahead assertion like F.J suggests in his/her answer, the latter can be shortened to:

```
^(?!\(.*[^)]$|[^(].*\)$)\(?\$?(0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(,?\d{3})?)(\.\d\d?)?\)?$
```

Comment: I forgot about leading zeros.  But your 2nd regexp example doesn't seem to run when tested, is it missing a parenthesis or something?

Comment: Dang it, my spec was wrong, if the dollar sign is used it must be INSIDE the parenthesis.

Comment: @gfrobenius: Re: second example: It works in Perl. I'm betting that ColdFusion doesn't like the `\d{,2}` notation; I'll change it to `\d{0,2}`. Re: dollar sign inside parentheses: no problem, I'll fix that, too.

Answer (score 11):

Here is one shorter alternative (56 chars to your 114), which will work in almost all regex flavors:

```
^\$?(?=\(.*\)|[^()]*$)\(?\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})?(\.\d\d?)?\)?$
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/qtYHEVzVK7

Explanation:

```
^                # start of string anchor
\$?              # optional '$'
(?=              # only match if inner regex can match (lookahead)
   \(.*\)          # both '(' and ')' are present
   |               # OR
   [^()]*$         # niether '(' or ')' are present
)                # end of lookaheand
\(?              # optional '('
\d{1,3}          # match 1 to 3 digits
(,?\d{3})?       # optionally match another 3 digits, preceeded by an optional ','
(\.\d\d?)?       # optionally match '.' followed by 1 or 2 digits
\)?              # optional ')'
$                # end of string anchor
```

Comment: Uh, this doesn't match `1,000,000`. Unless I missed something?

Answer (score 3):

Given your examples, the following regular expression will work:

```
/^(\$?(?(?=\()(\())\d+(?:,\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?(?(2)\)))$/gm
```

(note: flags and delimiters are language dependent)

This regex sets an unnecessary backreference merely to save regex-length. You can ignore the second backreference. If this is intolerable the expression will become quite a bit longer.

Have a look here: http://regex101.com/r/fH3lV1

Comment: Note that the IF construct is not very common among the regex flavours.