# Format a dollar amount within a string using HTML tags

Tags: vb.net, string-formatting

I need to add formatting to a string within a containing string in VB.NET.

For example the entire containing string might be "You're eligible to receive a discount of $10.00 today." and I want to bold (< b >< /b >) only the price (in this case $10.00, but could be something like $5.00 as well). The containing string is stored in a database.

So right now I have something like the below to get the string:

```
'CHECK IF ODD OR EVEN ORDER ID NUMBER CODE HERE, IF EVEN NUMBER THE DISPLAY TEXT SHOULD DISPLAY BOLD PRICE
Function GetText()
    Dim strText As String = ""
    strText = dataset1.Tables(0).Rows(0)("displayText").ToString()
    return strText
End Function
```

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information on how you determine that "$10.00" should be bolded but not other parts?

Comment: Are you just wanting to add the <b></b> tags to the string or are you wanting to display it that way? Also what framework are you using? Winforms,Wpf or ASP.Net

Comment: It should be conditionally be adding <b></b> tags to the string, check my added comment in post...thanks.

Comment: @MarkHall I'm using ASP.NET, this is to display Text on a label, which is set by a function called in code-behind, which retrieves text from the database. I want the price text to be displayed on screen bolded, not show the < b > tags.

Comment: @kyle_13 that is going to depend on your container, I just answered the question on how to get the Tags into your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you know that your price contains the only dollar sign in your string, anything more complicated will probably require a regex.

Something like this.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim myString As String = "You're eligible to receive a discount of $10.00 today."

        Dim temp As String() = myString.Split(" "c)
        For x = 0 To temp.Length - 1
            If temp(x).Contains("$") Then
                temp(x) = "<b>" & temp(x) & "</b>"
            End If
        Next
        myString = String.Join(" ", temp)
        Console.WriteLine(myString)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Modified your GetText Function

```
Function GetText() As String
    Dim strText As String = dataset1.Tables(0).Rows(0)("displayText").ToString()
    Dim temp As String() = strText.Split(" "c)
    For x = 0 To temp.Length - 1
        If temp(x).Contains("$") Then
            temp(x) = "<b>" & temp(x) & "</b>"
        End If
    Next
    Return strText = String.Join(" ", temp)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim input As String = "You're eligible to receive a discount of $10.00 today."
Dim re As New Regex(
  "(?!\(.*[^)]$|[^(].*\)$)\(?\$?(0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(,?\d{3})?)(\.\d\d?)?\)?")
Dim output As String = re.Replace(input, AddressOf MakeBold)
```

Assuming this is declared somewhere:

```
Function MakeBold(m As Match) As String
  Return String.Format("<b>{0}</b>", m.ToString())
End Function
```

Because it's using Regex, it will gladly accept multiple amounts for processing, i.e. a string like:

> You're eligible to receive a discount of $10.00 today and an additional discount of $5.00 tomorrow.

Replacing it with this:

> You're eligible to receive a discount of **$10.00** today and an additional discount of **$5.00** tomorrow.

*(Note: `<b></b>` tags were correctly interpreted by HTML parser of StackOverflow)*

You may want to adjust the regular expression to suit your needs. As currently written, it should match anything that looks like a dollar amount.

References:

- [Regex.Replace Method (String, MatchEvaluator) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- [Currency Regular Expression @ StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848570/currency-regular-expression)