# Regular Expression For Currency

Tags: regex

I have numbers like this

12,555,666.0000 [valid]

125,636.0000 [valid]

1,256.0000 [valid]

12,56..0000[invalid]

12*565.54.00

Now I need a regex for this where I have to make sure

1. This number does not contain a special character except(,) and just one decimal point (.)

I tried something like this `^[\d,]*\.{0,1}\d{0,4}$` but it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Currency Regular Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848570/currency-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
^\d+(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,4})?$
```

1. Start with one or more digits `^\d+`
2. Followed by (comma and three digits) zero or more times `(\,\d{3})*`
3. Followed by (point and 1 to four digits) zero or one time `(\.\d{1,4})?`
4. End `$`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/uO4qX2/1