# Separate currency from amount

Tags: regex, scala, currency

So i want to parse my string that contains value with currency, for example:

```
€579,976
€0
$1.5
```

Currently i am just removing the first `char` and trying to parse the rest.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it in a better way?

Comment: Not all characters can be represented in 1 character, so if you are just using the currencies that can be represented in a single character, then you don't need an optimization.

Comment: just use a regex: 1st group - currency symbol - NaN, 2nd group - floating point with thousand separator.

Comment: Can i have code example ?

Comment: which part are you having problem with? regex or scala code?

Comment: regex, i try to learn it but it seems difficult

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848570/currency-regular-expression

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `regular expression` to solve that problem.
There is a `Unicode Character Property` for Currencies : `\p{Sc}`.

## Usage Example, currency and amount:

```
val amountAndCurrencyRe = "(\\p{Sc})(.*)".r

val results = amountAndCurrencyRe.findAllIn("""€579,976  
  €0 
  $1.5
  ¥20
""")

results.collect{ 
 case amountAndCurrencyRe(currency,amount) =>
   println(s"Amount:$amount Currency:$currency") 
}.toList
```

### Result:

```
scala> results.collect{ case amountAndCurrencyRe(currency,amount) => println(s"Amount:$amount Currency:$currency") }.toList
Amount:579,976  Currency:€
Amount:0 Currency:€
Amount:1.5 Currency:$
Amount:20 Currency:¥
res6: List[Unit] = List((), (), (), ())
```

## just get Amounts:

```
scala> "€579,976  €0 $1.5 ¥20".replaceAll("\\p{Sc}","")
res1: String = 579,976  0 1.5 20
```

Comment: I don't need this currency, also not list, just simple string without the currency.