# Regex/grep strings containing us currency

Tags: regex, r

I have a list of strings, some of which contain dollar figures.  For example:

```
'$34232 foo    \n  bar'
```

is there an `[r]` command that can return to me only the strings which contain dollar amounts in them?

Thank you!

Comment: Already answered here, more or less: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354044/what-is-the-best-u-s-currency-regex

Comment: by the way, if you are thinking of your example as "a list of strings" (it's not; it's a length-1 character vector) you may want to use `strsplit(z,"[[:space:]]+")[[1]]` to convert it to a character vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\\$` to protect the `$` which otherwise means "end of string":

```
   grep("\\$[0-9]+",c("123","$567","abc $57","$abc"),value=TRUE)
```

This will select strings that contain a dollar sign followed by one or more digits (but not e.g. `$abc`).  `grep` with `value=FALSE` returns the indices. `grepl` returns a logical vector. One R-specific point is that you need to specify `\\$`, not just `\$` (i.e. an additional backslash is required for protection): `\$` will give you an "unrecognized escape" error.

@Cerbrus's answer, `'\\$[0-9,.]+'`, will match slightly more broadly (e.g. it will match `$456.89` or `$367,245,100`).  It will also match some implausible currency strings, e.g. `$45.13.89` or `$467.43,2,1` (i.e. commas should be allowed only for groupings of 3 digits in the dollars segment; there should be only one decimal point separating dollars and cents). Both of our answers will (incorrectly?) match `$45abc`. If you're lucky, your data don't have contain any of these tricky possibilities. Getting this right *in general* is hard; the answer referred to in the comments ( [What is "The Best" U.S. Currency RegEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354044/what-is-the-best-u-s-currency-regex) ) tries to do this, and as a result has significantly more complex answers, but could be useful if you adapt the answers to R by protecting `$` appropriately.

Comment: If all you are doing is `grep`, i.e. looking for a match, then you don't need the `+` because if there is 1 number after the `$` then there is at least one.  Leaving out the `+` could possibly speed things up (though the speedup may be too small to care about unless these are very long vectors).  The `+` is important for substitutions or extracting the number.

Answer (score 3):

Sure there is:

```
'\\$[0-9,.]+'

\\$ //Dollar sign
[0-9,.]+ // One or more numbers, dots, or comma's.
```

Comment: In R, one would have to use double `\\`.