# R regex: retrieve currency abbreviations

Tags: r, regex

I have a string of variable names and I want to extract the currencies as given by a vector from that. But I am having difficulties extracting the values.

My first approach was to replace all but the currencies abbreviations with nothing.

For example:

```
x <- c("Total Assets in th USD", "Equity in mil EUR", "Number of Branches")
currencies <- c("USD", "EUR", "GBP")

regex <- paste0("([^",
                paste(currencies, collapse = "|"),
                "])")
# results in
# "([^USD|EUR|GBP])"

gsub(regex, "", x)
# [1] "USD"  "EEUR" "B"
```

The expected result would be `c("USD", "EUR", "")`

This is obviously  wrong, as it matches the individual characters (E, U, R) instead of the character group (EUR). Now my question is, how can I extract only the given groups?

Comment: you can get a simple list of what matches what by just `sapply(currencies, function(y){ grep(pattern = y,  x,value = F) })`

Comment: If I search for `[r] regex currency` I find only one post that is related but but does not solve my issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159690/regex-grep-strings-containing-us-currency). Can you please ellaborate?

Comment: Darn. I got your post conflated with another one. If you just do any sort of edit (such as removing that unnecessary "thankyou" that is deprecated on SO) then my downvote can be reversed.

Comment: No worries, that is why i asked! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
x <- c("Total Assets in th USD", "Equity in mil EUR", "Number of Branches")
currencies <- c("USD", "EUR", "GBP")

regex <- paste0("\\b(",
                    paste(currencies, collapse = "|"),
                ")\\b")
# results in
# "\b(USD|EUR|GBP)\b"

regmatches(x, gregexpr(regex, x))
```

See the [R demo online](http://ideone.com/jRoMPh)

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "USD"

[[2]]
[1] "EUR"

[[3]]
character(0)
```

If the currencies appear "glued" to numbers, you need to remove the word boundaries (`\b`).

Comment: Also, if you need to unlist the results and get empty strings, you might want to have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/Yvc1EA). *stringr* functions  do that job cleaner though.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, paste(currencies, collapse="|"))
#[1] "USD" "EUR" NA
```

---

Or using `sub` from `base R`

```
v1 <- sub(paste0(".*\\b(", paste(currencies, collapse="|"), ")\\b.*"), "\\1", x)
replace(v1, !v1 %in% currencies, "")
#[1] "USD" "EUR" ""
```

Comment: Can we use base regex only?

Comment: @David Posted a base R option