# Codeigniter regex_match with money

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I am using code igniters form_validation and I was wondering if there was away to validate money for a text box for an example allow 4 numbers and then a period and then 2 numbers.

This what I got so far

```
regex_match[/^[0-9.]{0,7}+$/]
```

It works well, but I can enter a number like 100.000, is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354044/what-is-the-best-u-s-currency-regex

Answer (score 1):

To match exactly as you are requesting this would do it:

```
regex_match[/^\d{4}\.\d{2}$/] // allow 4 numbers only a period and then two numbers only
```

If you want to match UP TO 4 numbers so allow 1.00, 10.00, 100.00 but not more than 4 numbers before the decimal then use this:

```
regex_match[/^\d{1,4}\.\d{2}$/]
```