# Java Regular expression for money

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee, logic

I wan to make regex for money that can validate amount with **Commas, assumed decimals, negative sign or parentheses, dollar sign, decimals, numeric only.**

I have used the following expression

```
((\\$?(([0-9]{0,1})?\\.[0-9]{1,2}))|(\\$?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}([,][0-9]{3})*)(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?))
```

It works fine for $23,000 etc. but how to handle negative sign or parentheses

Please advice.

Comment: Try, post, and we'll give you an offer you can't refuse.

Comment: It's amazing that i lost so much reputation by asking question :) it's really de-fostering the user's trust on such system...

Comment: @deadlock I did it, its not working..

Comment: @Imran - you might want to read through the FAQ on [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you read through and post more detailed questions in the future they won't get down-voted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currency amount US & EU (cents optional) Can use US-style **123,456.78** notation and European-style **123.456,78** notation. Optional thousands separators; optional two-digit fraction

```
Match; JGsoft:
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:[0-9]*(?:[.,][0-9]{2})?|(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?|(?:\.[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9]{2})?)$
```

Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354044/what-is-the-best-u-s-currency-regex?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: What the? That's some super regex. I bet only aliens can read that.

Comment: @vikingsteve, why? That only basic stuff in that regex, no advanced regex feature used.