# Regex to match number range?

Tags: regex

How do I match two numbers, each preceded by dollar signs and with a hyphen between them, such as '$1,000 - $2,000'. I'd like to get the full range with the dollar signs included.

'$1,000 - $2,000'

Other examples:

'$30 - $40'

'$1-$2'

---

I've tried: `([\$0-9, -]*){1}` It doesn't work when there are characters before.

Comment: You can match `$1,000 - $2,000` in the string `$1,000 - $2,000` using the regular expression `.*`. To get a good answer to a regular expression question, you need to be a lot clearer about 1) what kinds of variable things you want to match, 2) what kinds of things look similar that you *don't* want to match, and 3) what the input looks like that contains the things from 1) and 2)

Comment: For the actual pattern '$1,000 - $2,000' or for anything in that range with a dollar sign and a comma for thousands?

Comment: what about decimals `.`, two digits or no `.`? what about leading zeros? Is the `,` optional or do you have to build groups of 3 digits? Is the amount of spaces between the hypen optional? Is the `$` mandatory? Is there an upper bound? Do you also accept negative amounts?

Comment: [I've answered a similar question, it wouldn't be hard to make it work for your case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242449/regex-currency-validation)

Answer (score 1):

```
\$1[0-9][0-9][1-9]\s
```

That seems simple to me...if you are excluding 1000 and  2000...if this is including 1000 and 2000 then

```
\$((1[0-9][0-9][0-9])|(2000))\s
```

There is surely a cleaner way to do it...but this will do the job

**********************edit*************************

Now that you changed your question... I think a simple regex would be

```
\$[0-9]*\s?\-\s?\$[0-9]*\s?
```

Dollar sign followed by any amount of numbers,

optional white space,

dash,

optional white space,

dollar sign followed by any numbers,

optional white space.

Comment: you could remove the braces around 2000 and the other numbers and you could write [0-9]{3} but whether this is cleaner or not is probably a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

To match '$1,000 - $2,000', you just use '$1,000 - $2,000' as the regular expression. To match anything in the range 1000 - 2000 with the format $x,xxx, use the regex:

```
'\$1,\d{3}|\$2,000'
```

To match any *range* between with 1000 as lower bound and 2000 as upper bound with the format $x,xxx - $x,xxx, use the regex:

```
'\$1,\d{3}|\$2,000 - \$1,\d{3}|\$2,000'
```

Comment: `\$[12],\d{3}` matches `2,999`