# Regular Expression for Currency

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to Regular Expression concept.

I tried to make currency regular expression in which

1. Amount should be a formatted number string, using ‘,’ for the thousands separator and ‘.’ for the decimal separator.
2. Amount should have exactly 2 decimal places
3. Amount should be a nonzero,positive value

I tried this

```
test1= /^\d{1,3}?([,]\d{3}|\d)*?\.\d\d$/;
test1.test(1,100.00);
```

But its not fulfilling my requirements.Suggest me how come i achieve this.

Comment: I think you tested `test1.test("1,100.00");`, didn't you? Try [`/^(?!0+\.0+$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}|\d)*\.\d{2}$/.test("1,100.00")`](https://regex101.com/r/uI8rR1/1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex currency validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242449/regex-currency-validation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to disallow `0.00` value, and allow numbers without a digit grouping symbol, you can use

```
 /^(?!0+\.0+$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}$/.test(your_str)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI8rR1/2)

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!0+\.0+$)` - negative lookahead that fails the match if the input is zero
- `\d{1,3}`  - 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*` - 0+ sequences of a comma followed with 3 digits
- `\.` - a literal dot
- `\d{2}` - 2 digits (decimal part)
- `$` - end of string.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = /^(?!0+\.0+$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}|\d)*\.\d{2}$/.test("1,150.25");
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>" + /^(?!0+\.0+$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}|\d)*\.\d{2}$/.test("0.25");

document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>" + /^(?!0+\.0+$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}$/.test("25");
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>" + /^(?!0+\.0+$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}$/.test("0.00");
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>" + /^(?!0+\.0+$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}$/.test("1150.25");
```

Comment: this is giving true in case of (1150.25) which should be false in my case.

Comment: Why should it be false if you added `\d` to the alternation? Then, you need to remove that alternative. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really work well. I am still new to Regular Expression This will really help me

Comment: this is good but how I do make the comma as optional? So this number `11232339.90` would be accepted? Thanks

Comment: @sg552 See the code snippet, `/^(?!0+\.0+$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}|\d)*\.\d{2}$/`

Comment: Hi it's me again. I tried to group the decimal to `/^(?!0+\.0+$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}|\d)(*\.\d{2})?$/` so decimal point would be optional and this number can be accepted `341` but it didn't work. Can you help me please?

Comment: @sg552 You need to use `(?:` and `)?` to wrap the optional pattern, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI8rR1/15).

Comment: I need help extending the regex. How can I not accept `0`, `00`, `000`, `0.00` or anything that just plain `0` number from this regex? `^(?!0+\.0+$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}|\d)*(?:\.\d{2})?$` . But `0.01` is accepted

Answer (score 1):

If your minimum value is `1.00`:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d\d$
```

This doesn't allow leading zeros.

Comment: Well, OP did not mention it, but if leading zeros are allowed, this won't work either.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Right, I've added a notice about.