# Regular Expression for custom price filter

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a regex for prices in specific formats.

Valid inputs are:

- Natural Numbers
- Decimals(upto two places after decimal point) except 0.0 and 0.00
- All the above criteria without leading zeroes (ex- 05 and 08.45 are invalid but 5 and 8.45 are valid)

Examples of valid test cases

```
1
11
0.10
0.01
1.1
1.00
11.11
```

Examples of invalid test cases

```
0
0.
0.0
0.00
0.000
01
001
1.
1.111
1111.1111
00.1
00.11
01.11
```

Here's what I have tried but can't get it to work

```
/^(((?!0)\d+)(.\d{1,2})?)|(0\.(([1-9]\d)|(0[1-9])))$/gm
```

See [Demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/k8UPLD/1).

```
/^[1-9]+[0-9]*(.\d{1,2})?$/gm
```

See [Demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/DE9FED/1).

The solution in [Regular Expression for Currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595165/regular-expression-for-currency) doesn't work for me as it validates `00.11` successfully.

Edit : I guess with some fiddling, I got it right this time. Just changed the `[1-9]` to `[0-9]` and it worked.

```
^(?![0.]*$|0+[0-9])\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

See [Demo #3](https://regex101.com/r/LawwUK/1).

All thanks to [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) for helping this newbie out. Much appreciated sir.

Comment: `^(?![0.]*$|0+[1-9])\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$`? See https://regex101.com/r/uFSPP5/1

Comment: It's accepting "1." too as shown in your link sir. Thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: It is not clear what you need to accept and what not. Try `^(?![0.]*$|0+[1-9])\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` then. See https://regex101.com/r/uFSPP5/2. Also, please check the duplicate question and update your question with your findings (whether the solutions there work for you or not).

Comment: Sorry for troubling again but it also accepts "000000.80", "00.80" etc which are still invalid. Kindly have a look if possible https://regex101.com/r/uFSPP5/3

Comment: Then make sure you use a more specific title and add all valid/invalid test cases to the question. You must also explain why that duplicate is not helpful.

Comment: Sir, the duplicate also marks the input pointed out by me earlier as valid. For example, it marks "00.80" as valid. I will try and update this question according to my specific requirement though. Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Updated my question as per your advice sir.

Comment: You can also use `^(?![0.]*$|0\B)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/uFSPP5/5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```cs
^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$|0+\d)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/T0Dac3/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0+                       '0' (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      0+                       '0' (1 or more times (matching the
                               most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0+                       '0' (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,2}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```