# Check if value is NaN but allow special chars

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, nan, dom-events

I have this validation check:

```
if (isNaN($scope.QuickQuoteData.RequestedAmount)) {
    $scope.ShowValidation = true;
    $scope.errors.push('Requested amount has invalid value.');
}
```

But what I want to allow is for example if user will enter values in this format:

```
€ 1500000
€ 1.500.000
1.500.000
```

Then I need to allow the operation to continue instead of throwing validation error.

So every other format will be invalid except the input values in the formats above.

Any idea how can I tweak that?

Comment: Use a regular expression. There's a lot around for validating currency strings if you search.

Comment: I think Intl(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object has some support for parsing numeric inputs based on different locales .

Comment: Hi you can have a look here, but consider that in the linked example they use the dollar sign, and they use commas and dots in the opposite way compared to your example (I guess you want comma for decimals and dot for thousands/millions etc.)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242449/regex-currency-validation

Answer (score 1):

you can check with below method

```
if (!("Any Number with special chars".test(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/))) { ... }
```

This will check if provided number has String or not
will  not check for Special Chars...

Answer (score 0):

As my understating for your requirement, you can do somthing like this.

```
var specialChars=[".", "$", "€"]; //Add your symbols whatever you need.

function validate(val){
  for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++){
    if(specialChars.indexOf(val[i]) >= 0) {
      continue;
    }
    if(isNaN(val[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but what if the user will enter €asodkao as a input value?

Comment: You need to call this `validate()` function on `key events`. It will work as expected.

Comment: @Laziale answer edited, plz check once. now you can pass whole value instead of a single `char`