# Does a string contain a price?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to check whether or not a string such as "The computer costs $2,000" contains a price or not.

I slightly [modified this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16242575/1422062) to fit my needs and the current regex that I am using looks like this:

```
var regexTest = /(?=.)^\$(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/;
```

If I do `regexTest.test("$2,000");` it will return true. However, if I add additional characters to the string such as `regexTest.test("The computer costs $2,000");` it will return false.

How should I modify the regex code in order to return true for the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove your `^` in regex. try this one

Also I recommend to remove `$` as well so price like this `$5.000,00 words` will return `true`

```js
var regexTest = /(?=.)\$(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?/;

console.log(regexTest.test('computer $5,000.00'));
console.log(regexTest.test('$5,000.00'));
console.log(regexTest.test('$5,000.00 that was computer price'));
console.log(regexTest.test('computer 5,000.00'));
```

Comment: maybe update your snippet with failure scenario too.

Comment: @RizkiDPrast exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The global modifier should work. Add the `g` after the last /

```
var regexTest = /(?=.)^\$(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/g;
```

Should match with all instances inside the test string.