# Regex number with digits calculation

Tags: regex

I would like a salary field that only takes numbers and also numbers with maximum 2 digits after the dot.  Spaces and commas are not allowed.

My RegEx below is not working it allows spaces and commas and it allows more than 2 digits after the comma

`("^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:[0-9]*(?:[.'][0-9]{2})?|(?:'[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?|(?:\.[0-9]{3})*(?:'[0-9]{2})?)$");`

The following is what should be accepted

```
10000
10000.00
```

The following should not be accepted

```
10,000
10'000
10000.456
1000.47888
10 000
```

Comment: Should be accepted `#` or `#.#` ? Why is that ? An input field should accept `#`, `#.#`, `#.`, `.#`. What is a user to think if he can't enter `10.` but can enter `10.0` ? He's gonna think the programmer is lame.

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered here:
[Regex currency validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242449/regex-currency-validation)
Solution is for JavaScript, but a regex can be generally used in every language

Comment: Correct but wrong. OP said `10,000` should not be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2}){0,1}$`

Explanation:

`\d+` - one or more digits

`(?:\.\d{1,2}){0,1}` - optional (happening once or not at all) dot followed by one or two digits

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

[REGEX101 DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Y3jDWg/2/)