# How to set up currency format for MVC EditorFor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, currency-formatting

I have to pages that need to show the item amount with currency format. The first one is where currency is entered and the second one where currency is displayed.

I would like the EditorFor to show an R indicated Rands and then i would like the value to be decimal.

Here is my EditorFor:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TransactionModel.Price)
</div>
```

I have tried many different ways and can't get any to work.

With this example below it does not know what 'CurrencyPrice' is in the second line.

```
var CurrencyPrice = '@Model.TransactionModel.Price';
document.getElementById('TransactionModel.Price').value = '@string.Format("{0:C}", CurrencyPrice)';
```

I have also tried these in my transactionModel:

```
//[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
//[UIHint("Currency")]
//[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
//[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Could someone please tell me how i can get this right?

Right now i will accept any working method.

Answer (score 2):

With MVC 4, you can use the TextBoxFor method that includes a format string:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TransactionModel.Price, "{0:c}")
```

In MVC 3 and below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TransactionModel.Price, 
    new { @Value = model.TransactionModel.Price.ToString("c") })
```

`EditorFor` might or might not work. Personally, I have had problems with it. For more inspiration, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2842587/2021517).

Comment: Both have not worked, i am using MVC 4. The textbox remains the same with formatting just a flat number.

Comment: Have you set the cultureinfo in your web.config? In the `<system.web>` section: `<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" culture="en-ZA" uiCulture="en-ZA" />`. That works for me for displaying an R for rands.

Comment: I set that, and it had no effect.

Comment: Well then I do not have more suggestions. I have verified that TextBoxFor creates an input textbox with R prefixed in my MVC project when setting the culture to en-ZA so I do not understand why it does not work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the above to work for me.  This is the solution I came up with that worked using Data Annotation on the Model.

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Average Yearly Salary")]
[Numeric]
[RegularExpression(@"^\$?\-?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\-?\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\(\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))\)$", ErrorMessage = "The value must be in currency format ")]
[StringLength(12)]
```

I got the RegEx from JohnM [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354044/what-is-the-best-u-s-currency-regex).

This should REALLY not be this hard for everyone!  I was very surprised I had to put forth so much effort on validating currency in an ASP.NET application!!!  What should have taken 30 seconds, took hours of research and testing.