# Java Regular Expression to match dollar amounts

Tags: java, regex

This is what i've been using

```
\$?[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*
```

But when i was doing some testing i noticed that things like

```
$$$34.00
```

would return as a match (but `matcher.group()`) just returns the matched substring. I don't want it to even pass the regular expression if the user enters more than one dollar sign so i tried this:

```
\${1}[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*
```

but this seems to behave the same as the regular expression i first typed. Right now i'm testing this in java but, i plan to use it in c++ using the Boost libraries. But Please don't give me that solution here because i'm trying to learn without someone giving me the answer.

But i do need help making it so the user can only enter one dollar sign (which is what i thought `\${1}` would do)

Comment: Wouldn't it also allow a bunch of periods in a row?

Comment: you can specify the begin and end of a string like ^\${1}[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*$

Comment: Is the amount the whole string? Also, how do you match it currently? Using `.find()`?

Comment: Yes i'm using `matcher.find()`

Comment: @Eric.K.Yung looks like ^\$?[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*$ does what i want. I want the user to be able to enter a dollar amount with a dollar sign or w/o a dollar sign

Comment: I know this is an old question but this website REALLY helped me understand RegEx 
https://regexr.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you're doing this to learn regex...

`^\$(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|(([1-9]\d*)?\d))(\.\d\d)?$`

Breakdown:

`^\$` start of string with $ a single dollar sign

`([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)` 1-3 digits where the first digit is not a 0, followed by 0 or more occurrences of a comma with 3 digits

or

`(([1-9]\d*)?\d)` 1 or more digits where the first digit can be 0 only if it's the only digit

`(\.\d\d)?$` with a period and 2 digits optionally at the end of the string

Matches:

```
$4,098.09
$4098.09
$0.35
$0
$380
```

Does not match:

```
$098.09
$0.9
$10,98.09
$10,980456
```

Comment: `(([1-9]\d*)?\d)` also takes care if the user does not enter commas doesn't it?

I'm glad you posted this answer because i really learned alot from breaking up that regex myself and understanding it piece by piece

Comment: Yes, that portion is specifically to capture when no commas are used in the string.

Comment: What is the opposite to get the $amount alone

Answer (score 19):

I would suggest **avoiding the use of regular expressions for currency parsing, esp when Java provides you much simpler ways to solve this problem.**

Consider this code:

```
String str = "$789.11"; // user entered value
Number number = null;
try {
    number = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).parse(str);
} catch(ParseException pe) {
    // ignore
}

if (number != null) {
   // proceed as user entered a good value
}
else {
   // user didn't enter a good value
}
```

Comment: shame I can't +1 this more times

Comment: This is pretty neat and i will definitely store it away in my toolbox but, I am trying to learn regular expressions so that was why i was trying to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Yes sure, its your prerogative. However just to let you know currency string can contain comma as well e.g. `$23,456.78`

Comment: @rage: Check this answer for some pointers about using regex to parse US currency string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354044/what-is-the-best-u-s-currency-regex

Comment: The `.parse(str)` method accepts incorrect strings like `$12asdf`.

Comment: I agree with Dean.  I don't think the main response is +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like `[^\$]*\$?` in the beginning. This would insure that there are no duplicate $ signs, but also matches if there is no $ present.

Also, if you are working with currency (possible decimal and 2 digits after), you should use `[\.\d{2}]?.`

This says that it can be a match if it's followed by ONE instance of a period and 2 digits or nothing at all. As stated in the comments, it can also match multiple periods in a row, so you shouldn't use the `*` quantifier after `\.`

Comment: I didn't want to force the user into adding cents if he didn't need to.  . would `\.{0,1}` work for that?

Comment: `\.?` is the same as `\.{0,1}`.The `?` quantifier means it happens either once or not at all. You should also include the two possible cent digits after the period as I showed in my answer. Without them, `$27.50` would only match `$27.`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `^`(beginning of string),`$`(end of string)

```
^\$\d+([.][0-9]+)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this is coming late but this seems to work for me

```
(\$)?[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*
```

i dont understand why it didnt work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`[$](([1-9]+\.?\d*)|([0]\.\d*)|[0])` pattern ideally for this case.

This is standard Perl regex but could be use in JAVA with some libs.