# replace dollar amount with 0.00 with regex-replace

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, replace

Seems pretty simple but i'm having problems coming up with a good method to do this.  This should be possible with the regex.replace in .NET VB...  Sorry but I'm fairly rookie at Regex...

I have a long string with contains a sales receipt.... I do not want to display the dollar amounts under certain instances, so i want to replace all amounts with 0.00 before displaying the string. ie.

**original string:**

*Order Details:
    item one
        1 @ $33.99  $33.99
    item two
        100 @ $3.99 $399.00
    item three
        10 @ $333.99    $3339.90
    Subtotal: 33333.99
    Shipping: 10.27
    Tax: 0.00
    Total: 444444.26*

**after replace:**

*Order Details:
    item one
        1 @ $0.00   $0.00
    item two
        100 @ $0.00 $0.00
    item three
        10 @ $0.00  $0.00
    Subtotal: 0.00
    Shipping: 0.00
    Tax: 0.00
    Total: 0.00*

Thanks,
Todd.

Answer (score 2):

**Regex**

```
\d+\.\d{2}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/kXE-cY9dSknjtaVK)

**Description**

This will find all your numbers then simply replace with 0.00

If you wanted something that found the `$` symbol as well the below regex would be right:

```
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}$
```

This finds groups of 3 with `,` as well however that isn't what your example showed.

Answer (score 1):

See this:

[What is "The Best" U.S. Currency RegEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354044/what-is-the-best-u-s-currency-regex)

Replace on this expression: `[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}` and you'll get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}", "0.00");
```

See working [`demo`](http://regex101.com/r/vM9xH9)

Comment: fyi, the part that makes sure `,`s appear with exactly 3 digits afterwards doesn't work- it actually checks for at least 3.

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `(\$)[\d.]+|(otal:)\s*[\d.]+` with `g` Option
and replace with `$1$2 0.00` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nR6kV7)