# Javascript Regex to match currency

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find and match currency in a given text. Formats that are accepted are:

- $10
- $10.25
- $999,000
- $2 billion
- $625 million

This is my regex so far:

```
var money_vals =  $('body').text().match(/\$\d+\.?\d+(\,\d+)?(thousand|million|billion|trillion)?/g);
```

However, it doesn't match $2 billion or the $625 million or any value followed by million/billion/trillion.
Also, after adding $5 to one of the paragraphs in my text, I realized it doesn't get matched.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Try the following: \$\d+((,|\.)\d+)?(\s(thousand|million|billion|trillion))?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "The Best" U.S. Currency RegEx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354044/what-is-the-best-u-s-currency-regex)

Comment: Most currency symbols are usually written as postfix (dollar is not the only currency in the world).

Comment: This worked for me: var money_vals = $('body').text().match(/\$\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?(thousand| million| billion| trillion|$)?/g);

Answer (score 2):

A generic form, group 1 matches the number second group the following boundary word

```
\$[\s]?([\d\.\,]+)[\s]*([\w]*)
```

http://regexr.com/3c3av

An exact match form :

```
\$[\s]?([\d\.\,]+)[\s]*(thousand|million|billion|trillion)?
```

http://regexr.com/3c3as

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following regex:

```
/\$\d+[\,\.\d\s]*(?:thousand|million|billion|trillion|$)/ig
```

Comment: It only matches $2 billion and $625 million

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var re = /\$[0-9]+[?:, 0-9]*(?:billion|million+)?/;
var sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
var results = [];
var i = 0;
for (var matches = re.exec(sourcestring); matches != null; matches = re.exec(sourcestring)) {
 results[i] = matches;
for (var j=0; j<matches.length; j++) {
  alert("results["+i+"]["+j+"] = " + results[i][j]);
}
i++;
```

}

This will solve your problem.