# Regex to account for any dollar amount entry, including just decimal values without grouping

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to account for the possibility of any USD denomination and I came up with this:

```
\$\d+\.?\,?\d+\.?\d+
```

This works for entries like **$10,500.23, $1,050.23, $105.23, $105, $10, $1**

But won't work for things like **$.23**

I tried using `\d+?` instead of just `\d?` but that doesn't seem to work either (maybe there is a special way of handling this that I'm unaware of?)

Comment: Try [`\$(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d*)(?:\.\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/mOaGLv/2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "The Best" U.S. Currency RegEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354044/what-is-the-best-u-s-currency-regex)

Answer (score 0):

The `+` symbol means one or more, whereas the `?` symbol means 0 or 1. If you add an OR statement (`|`) you can have it work with either, making the completed (and fully functional) statement `\$\d+|\d?\.?\,?\d+\.?\d+`

one potential issue with this is that the regex doesn't catch items with only one digit after the `.`, not sure if that is an issue for you in your implementation or not.