# Match Two Regular Expressions in String

Tags: c#, regex, selenium-webdriver

I have this text "£24,250.00 (inc. VAT)"

I want a regex that will show ONLY "24250.00"

I've managed to get the last portion with:

```
( \(inc\. VAT\))
```

And separately I can get the £ and , with:

```
[£,]
```

But I can't seem to work out how to combine both expressions to just return what I want.

Note that the number is dynamic so will change depending on applicable costs on a website.

In theory I could just run it through two separate regex in my c# code each one trimming what I want. But is there a way that it can be done with just one expression?

Reason for this is I have a GetConvertedExtension method that takes an IWebElement, a string (the regex) and then converts the string to Double, Int etc

I don't really want to change this extension method or avoid using and going down the root of multiple expressions and then a parse statement.

I've used https://regexr.com/ to try getting a working solution but with no luck and starting to struggle.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and C# with the Regex library

Comment: You could use match £ and the comma and use 2 capturing groups for what you want to keep `£(\d+),(\d+\.\d+) \(inc\. VAT\)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OTQEZ0/1) Do the numbers always end with a dot and 2 digits (or more)?

Comment: I think you could probly copy this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354044/what-is-the-best-u-s-currency-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a single regex, you could use 2 capturing groups:

```
£(\d+),(\d+\.\d+) \(inc\. VAT\)
```

Then you could use group1 and group2 after each other to get your value.

If the decimal part after the dot can contain only 2 digits, replace the last `\d+` with `\d{2}`

For example:

```
string pattern = @"£(\d+),(\d+\.\d+) \(inc\. VAT\)";
string input = @"£24,250.00 (inc. VAT)";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Result

```
24250.00
```

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%c2%a3%28%5cd%2b%29%2c%28%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%29+%5c%28inc%5c.+VAT%5c%29&i=%c2%a324%2c250.00+%28inc.+VAT%29&r=%241%242) | [C# Demo](https://ideone.com/KUhcvT)

Comment: thanks - this has done the trick...and not too overly complicated. The grouping method used did the tricks...never thought to capture the individual groups and then recombine

Answer (score -1):

`(?<currency>[£$€])(?<value>[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2})\s\(inc\.\sVAT\)`

I would use sometihng like this. I added the first capture group with currency just as I thought maybe this could be useful too? You'd just have to add which currency symbols you are interested in the square brackets.

In visual studio you:

`var regex = new Regex(@"(?<currency>[£$€])(?<value>[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2})\s\(inc\.\sVAT\)");`

Then you do your regex.Match(data) or regex.Matches(data) or whatever you need to do.

Then to access the number in your match you need to access the value group so... `match.Groups["value"].Value` where match is what you've assigned to be your regex match.

Just to quickly run through the regex:

`(?<currency>[£$€])` this is a named capture group which will capture `£` or `$` or `€` literally.

`(?<value>[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2})` This is named capture group to get the number. Further breaking it down:

`[0-9]{1,3}` matches a digit from 0 to 9 between 1 and 3 (inclusive) times.
`(?:,[0-9]{3})*` matches the thousands seperated by commas 0 or more times.
`\.[0-9]{2}` matches the decimal point and two digits after.

`\s\(inc\.\sVAT\)` This matches literally the inc VAT bit after number. Using `\s` instead of  as whitespace because I find it easier to read.

NOTE: this regex only works for this number format with a comma for every thousand and always includes the decimal.